# Mongoose's model.update not working in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Node.js app that is updating data in a MongoDB database using Mongoose.

I have setup the Mongoose model and I am able to successfully use the model.find, and model.remove functions, but I can't get the model.update function to work.

Can anyone help me?

```
/* ------------------------ Finding/Querying works ----------------------
Flot.find({ "label": "Trips Per Day"}, function (err, docs) {
  res.jsonp(docs || err);
});
*/



/* ------------------------ Removing works -----------------------
Flot.remove({ "label": "Trips Per Client" }, function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  res.json(err || "removed");
});
*/


var conditions = { "label": "Average Tons per Delivery" };
var update = { "label": "Average Tons per Delivery 2" };
var options = { };
var callback = function callback(err, numberAffected, rawResponse) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);

  console.log('Error: ', err);
  console.log('NumberAffected: ', numberAffected);
  console.log('RawResponse: ', rawResponse);

    res.json(err || rawResponse || numberAffected );
};

 Gage.update( conditions, update, options, callback );
```

Comment: What doesn't work about what you're trying?

Comment: You're using the `Flot` model in the find and remove but `Gage` in the update.

Comment: Flot and Gage are both different collections/models, I have been trying to get it to work with both. The err is logged as null, the numberAffected shows up as 0, and the rawResponse shows up as undefined.

Comment: Then you don't have any docs in that collection that match `conditions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working with node-mongodb-native. I'm still not sure why Mongoose wasn't working, but at least I got something to work.

```
var query = {"label": "Average Tons per Delivery"};
var update = {"type": "vertical"};
var options = {};

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/db', function(err, db) {
  if(err) throw err;

db.collection('justgage').findAndModify(
    query,
    [['_id','asc']],
    {$set: update},
    options,
    function(err, object) {
      res.jsonp("Ok");
    });
});
```